# How does GStreamer manage threads when merging several branches (queue)

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have a GStreamer pipeline that records three live cameras and basically does the following: capture 3 cam in a first thread ; then do some processing over the 3 streams in 3 separate threads ; in parallel re-scale the frames for a **compositor** (videomixer adapted for live sources) in 3 other threads ; and finally do the composition. The plan for each camera is following (so x3) :

```
[capture] -> TEE |-> QUEUE -> [someProcessing] -> _
                 |-> QUEUE -> [rescale]        -> COMPOSITOR
```

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 \
${capture0} ! tee name='t0' ! queue ! ${someProcessing0} \
${capture1} ! tee name='t1' ! queue ! ${someProcessing1} \
${capture2} ! tee name='t2' ! queue ! ${someProcessing2} \
${someStuff} \
compositor name=compo ${compositorSinkProperties} \
t0. ! queue ! ${rescale0} ! compo.sink_0 \
t1. ! queue ! ${rescale1} ! compo.sink_1 \
t2. ! queue ! ${rescale2} ! compo.sink_2 \
-e
```

My pipeline works well, I just need to clarify it's internal behavior:

I know how to force using separate threads with the element **queue**. However I do not know what happens when my 3 [rescale] branches are merged inside a single element such as **compo** in my case.

*Does GStreamer create 3 threads as asked?*
*If yes, then in what thread(s) does **compositor** run?*
*If not, do I have only 1 thread for the whole **rescaling+compositing** process?*

Thanks for any info you might share!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you are correct. You will have threads for all the queue paths downstream. And I *think* the aggregator has its own thread too. I lack proof for it - perhaps you can discover it in the GstAggregator class.

But its `aggregate` function fires once all sink pads on the aggregator have data.

Taken from the base-classes documentation [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstAggregator.html#GstAggregatorClass.aggregate):

```
aggregate ()

Mandatory. Called when buffers are queued on all sinkpads. Classes should
iterate the GstElement->sinkpads and peek or steal buffers from the
GstAggregatorPads. If the subclass returns GST_FLOW_EOS, sending of the
eos event will be taken care of. Once / if a buffer has been constructed
from the aggregated buffers, the subclass should call _finish_buffer.
```

Comment: Thanks for the info !

You seem to be right about GstAggregator using its own thread : I tried running my pipeline using the -m option (printing bus message).. among tons of messages, I get a GstTask creation message whose owner is my compositor :

`
Got message #147 from pad "compo:src" (stream-status): GstMessageStreamStatus, type=(GstStreamStatusType)GST_STREAM_STATUS_TYPE_CREATE, owner=(GstElement)"\(GstCompositor\)\ compo", object=(GstTask)"\(GstTask\)\ compo:src";
`

(and then and stream-status message for entering the GstTask)

Anyway, thanks for pointing the  direction :)